# The "accepted" color is too light

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

*Please* considering changing into something which introduces contrast.

Comment: Which contrast you do want? (the first one is the current color) http://i.imgur.com/I3i2d.png

Comment: @KennyTM: The accepted color on meta is quite nice. I guess the difficulty with the main site is that the green of the text is also rather bright, leaving little room for the background to be darker without making the text unreadable. But FWIW, I like #2 or #3.

Comment: @KennyTM, to be honest, none of those! :) Something with character, like MO's #3b7a00

Comment: @Mariano: http://i.imgur.com/jPmCR.png? :p Anyway, seems like you mean we should use "white-on-green" for accepted answer like [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Surely, the font should be white for that bg color!

Comment: I don't understand why the site has so much text in subdued tones.

Comment: I mocked up Mariano's suggestion, and I like it: http://i.imgur.com/FtjCr.png

Answer (score 5):

I have updated the accepted answer text/bg colors to match Beta theme's. Should be more readable than before.

Comment: The "accepted answer" background looks good to me now, but the text colour is slightly bluer than the "answered" text colour, and that seems odd. Perhaps keep the bg colour but make the text colour match the green of the "answered" text.

Comment: @Rahul I have updated the accepted answer text color to match answered's. the change will be in the next deployment.

Comment: @Jin: It still looks the same to me. Can you check if the update has gone through?

Comment: @Rahul, we have tested the colors on several monitors, PC and Mac and they seem fine. I suggest you check your monitor's gamma setting. Are you on an old LCD monitor?

Comment: @Jin: Oh, I wasn't saying it's too light or hard to read. I was just trying to point out that `.answered {color: #209814;}` and `.answered-accepted {color: #418370;}` still don't match.

Comment: @Rahul, I see. I'll put that fix in soon.

Comment: @rahul the change is on production now.

Comment: @Jin: Thanks... I hate to nag, but I was hoping you'd change it the other way around, like I had suggested in my first comment. But if you feel it's better this way, I won't object.